# Custom options vs. Configurable product options?

Tags: php, magento

We have a big project next month and I'm really confused about using (Custom options) or (Attribut Set) for product...

We're planning to use **MAGMI**, is there a preference or prerequisites to use it effectively and import attributes such as color or sizes (case of clothes) ?

Thx in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between a configurable product and a product including custom options

Custom options
Inventory is not checked or updated for individual options during the purchase of the custom options. It depends on parent product inventory.

Configurable product
In configurable product each child product inventory is updated

Ex:
Custom options:-
Store is allowed to sell 3 glasses. Buyer selects the lens specification and seller manufactures it and sells it. Next inventory would be shown 2 glasses

Configurable product:-
Seller have 3 shirt 1 red,1blue,1white. If buyer buys 1 white shirt next time he cant buy white shirt

Most of the specifiactions uses configurable product.I think you need configurable product. Custom options are used in rare cases

Hope you got what was needed. :)

Comment: I'm seeing you asking people to accept your answers *a lot*. Just to make sure I'm clear; you should not do this any longer.

Answer (score 3):

I'll write my conclusion about this topic after some internet research

Use custom options if:

- You have a small catalog and are looking for a quick way to create customizable products.
- You don't need to manage inventory.
- You have a small catalog and want an easy way to offer product variations.
- The options are applied after the product is ordered, such as custom embroidery on a tee shirt.

Use a configurable product options if:

- You manage a large catalog of products with many variations.
- You want to manage inventory separately for each variation.
- You want each variation to have its own product page.

**MAGMI** is best option for all import products. I can import such color or sizes But it's interface is very complex so if someone could point me to the right way for such context I'll be grateful.